# React Native with JSON schema form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsonschema

I'm trying to find a way to implement `JSON schema` form into `React Native`, but I can't find a good solution.

My idea was to return a `JSF` (server-side) and use that to create a `form` in the app. So for instance, I could always make changes to the form without having to update the app.

I found a few interesting items:

- [schema to Yup](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/schema-to-yup#readme) ; but if I'm correct this will be used specifically for the validation side of the form and not the creation itself.
- [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form) ; This seems to be `React.js` only and [no support](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/696) for react-native (yet).
- [tcomb-form-native](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native) with the [JSF extension](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-json-schema) could be interesting but not very actively maintained.

Does someone have experience with this, and if so; how did you implement it?

**Update**

The idea is to use `redux-form` and abstract some values from the JSF.

```js
const Form = ({ ...props }) => {
const fields = fieldTypesFromJSF(schema);

  return (
    <Field name='name' {...fieldTypesFromJSF.name} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in server side you can define json like this 
   `formConfig:[{name:'username',type:'string'},{name:'family',type:'string'}]`
and in RN side formik is best choice because it has initialValues props can initialize base on formConfig

```
 <Formik
    initialValues={{name,family}}
     onSubmit={values => {
     this.props.handleSubmit(values);
     }}
        >
          {props => (
            <View>
              {this.props.formConfig.map(item => {
                const { name } = item;
                if (item.type === 'number') {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <View style={styles.column}>
                        <Input
                          value={props.values[name]}
                          onChangeText={props.handleChange(name)}
                        />
                        <Text>{props.values[name]}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </>
                  );
                }
              })}

              <Button onPress={props.handleSubmit} title="submit" />
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have experience with this actually. the way I did this was to get the form from an api as a json object and the root object which is a form would consist of an array of tables and each table would consist of an array of elements. and each element is an object describing the field of the form. and depending on the type element I had created custom components such as singleLineInput, multiLineInput, checkbox, radioButton, comboBox and would render accordingly using switch statement. I have simplified my answer just to give you a quick start. I was actually getting a lot of data in the json object describing the theme of the form and the version of the form. since each time I changed the form on web it created a new version and synced with the mobile app since the mobile app would work offline it had to be saved locally on mobile.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your response. I was actually writing some similarity to your implementation. I've updated my question with the idea.